# Need to convert data into Dat files via Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

I am new to Informatica so need your help.

I have one staging table where data comes everyday and I need to extract data from this staging table and convert it into Dat file format and place in into a folder. so that these dat files could be a feed for another process.

I dont know how informatica does this (Conversion of data from Staging table to Dat). So please help me to know how Informatica fetch the data from staging table, transform it into Dat file and place it into a folder.

Thanks & Regards,
Vikram

Comment: This is a bit of a vague question Vikram. Are you asking for a design pattern for extracting from a staging table, or general information about how to use Informatica? If the former, some details about how the staging table is updated would be useful - i.e. does it contain a timestamp? Can you use the timestamp to get the list of records which has changed since your last run? Are the staging table and .dat file formats basically the same, or are you performing any transformations (other than inserting delimiters, presumably)?

Comment: If you're looking for specific help on how to use Informatica, them the scope of the question is probably too wide to be answered usefully here. The best place to start is the built-in tutorials - they are very good and should help to answer many of your questions.

Comment: Hi Bob and Rajesh, Thanks for your reply. I understand the question is to wide to answer in simple words. Lets have simle requirment - we have 3 columns in a staging table - Name, Address and date. Everyday data comes into this. We need to pick only current day's data and convert it into .dat file pipe delimited. The each data field will be a separated by a pipe (‘|) and each record will start from a new line. The null fields will be populated with a blank and pipe delimiter if there are no values present for those fields.Iam asking for the design pattern also. How does Informatica convert it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a pipe-delimited flat file...

Go to the Target Designer - Select Target->Create then choose Flat File. Then double click on the file, and in the 'Table' tab, at the bottom right select 'Advanced' and choose your delimiter. Then you can add your columns, specify the file location and all is well!

Comment: I should have added this as a comment to your answer! +1'd too :)

Comment: Hi Bob/Rajesh, Thanks for you both for yours valuabe answers. Here I am looking one more thing. I want to FTP this .dat file to location. (Location path we knw). So is it possible with Informatica to FTP any output .dat file to a location. If yes, then help me know how? :) Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi Vikram, happy to help but you're likely to find people more keen to assist you if you accept some answers! Anyway, you can do this in two ways - either by using an FTP connection in your session parameters to modify where it puts the output file, or by running a command via the workflow after your process has run.. The steps for the former are: In Workflow Manager, Go to Connections->FTP and create a new FTP connection. Then in the task developer, create or edit a 'session' task, and in the 'mapping' tab, go to Targets then <your target file>, and select the FTP Connection you just created.

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks. I agree what are you saying to accept answers. I clicked on yes button of the quesion "Is this post helpfull" for this answer and did same before also. Is there anything esle I should do to accept answers.

Comment: Hi Vikram, yes - whichever answer is the most correct you can 'accept' which means that in future others can get the most relevant answer without looking through all of the answers. If you look at other questions you'll see that more of them have a green tick next to one of the answers, which is the 'accepted' one. Cheers!

Comment: HI Bob, Yes I got to know how to accept any answers :) Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define a source definition based on your staging table, a target definition based on your final file format and then create the mapping,session and workflow that link the two.

.Dat file is not a complete description for the file, since any file can be renamed to a .dat file. You'll need to decide how the data would be separated in this file (commas? tabs? pipes?). Remember all downstream processes will then use this file as input, so you need to publish this format too.

Comment: Hi Bob and Rajesh, Thanks for your reply. I understand the question is to wide to answer in simple words. Lets have simle requirment - we have 3 columns in a staging table - Name, Address and date. Everyday data comes into this. We need to pick only current day's data and convert it into .dat file pipe delimited. The each data field will be a separated by a pipe (‘|) and each record will start from a new line. The null fields will be populated with a blank and pipe delimiter if there are no values present for those fields.Iam asking for the design pattern also. How does Informatica convert it.

Comment: Vikram - Have you created the table source, file target and the mapping? which stage are you stuck at? DO you see any errors?

Comment: Rajesh, I stuck actually with target. how to create .dat file pipe delimited. Data is in Exp transformation and now need to send it to .dat file in a folder.